# Email validation not working accordingly

Tags: php, email

i made a form where people can enter their email. 
The problem is they can now add everything they want inside the field, I want them to only be able to enter a valid email. i found this piece of code on the internet.

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

And implemented it in my PHP mail sending code:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['subscribefield'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}


$to = "test@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
$body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "your mail was sent";
?>
```

Still doesn't work. What did i do wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Comment: What do you mean by _"Still doesn't work"_? What doesn't work? What is the input you are using and what is the expected result?

Comment: I basically typed something like "lalala" and it still sent :x @1615903

Comment: You are not using `$email` or `$emailErr` variables anywhere in your code. You are always sending to `test@hotmail.com`.

Comment: if(!filter....) { $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; echo $mailErr; die;} ... to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have if statement anywhere that would check $emailErr.
Such as:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}

if( isset($emailErr) === FALSE )
{
    $to = "test@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
    $body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);

    echo "your mail was sent";
}
```

Or simply

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "Invalid email format";
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not try to send if email address is wrong.

> ```
> $email = $_POST['subscribefield'];
>
> if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
>   {
>   $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
>   }
>   else
>   {
>   $to = "test@hotmail.com";
>   $subject = "Abonee voor de nieuwsbrief";
>   $body = "$email \n Heeft zich aangemeld voor de nieuwsbrief";
>   mail($to, $subject, $body);
>   echo "your mail was sent";
>   }
>
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting the error.
Try something like this:

```
    if (filter_var('test@hotmail.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
        echo 'VALID'; 
    //Do you email send stuff

    } else {
        echo 'NOT VALID';
    //Display the error and don't send the mail
    }
```